# How to use PassportJS with HapiJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, hapi.js

I'm having a hard time to decide the best way to use **PassportJS** with [**HapiJS**](https://github.com/spumko/hapi). Have anyone done that? I'm not talking about [**Travelogue**](https://github.com/spumko/travelogue) because I kinda didn't like the way it works. Maybe I'm not using it right.

Comment: You need to define an actual question here. And please edit your question with some code that you have tried and what problems you are currently having. Otherwise, this is likely to be considered "off-topic". More information in your edit will help you.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I'll do that.

Comment: I believe that the Traveloque is the only way to work with PassportJS in Hapi. Even so, the developers are thinking seriously in discontinue the project as you can see [here](https://github.com/hapijs/travelogue/issues/86) You could also try to use an alternative like [bell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bell)

Answer (score 4):

Travelogue has recently been "retired". Check out the replacement module [bell](https://github.com/hapijs/bell). bell is much more "hapi-like" because it doesn't try to use passport.js

Answer (score 0):

Passport is designed to work with middleware based frameworks. Hapi.js is a plugin based framework. Can you be a little more specific why you need passport?

If you are trying to use the socal auth (facebook, google, linkedin) then theres alternative in hapi.